# substring match in redshift database

Tags: regex, database, postgresql, amazon-redshift

I have a redshift table "person" in which a particular column has data something like this

```
[{"attributeName":"name","attributeMetadata":null,"attributeValue":"KitchenAid - 7-Speed Hand Mixer - White","attributeImageType":"PRODUCT","attributeStatusCodes":[]},
{"attributeName":"title","attributeMetadata":null,"attributeValue":"KitchenAid","attributeImageType":"PRODUCT","attributeStatusCodes":[]},

{"attributeName":"address","attributeMetadata":null,"attributeValue":"address","attributeImageType":"PRODUCT","attributeStatusCodes":[]},

{"attributeName":"PIN CODE","attributeMetadata":null,"attributeValue":"32110","attributeImageType":"IMG","attributeStatusCodes":[]}]
```

I would like to extract only the dictionary/json/substring containing `PIN CODE` (see below)

```
{"attributeName":"PIN CODE","attributeMetadata":null,"attributeValue":"32110","attributeImageType":"IMG","attributeStatusCodes":[]}
```

I tried the following query and it is giving the following error

```
select distinct regexp_substr(attributes,'.*({.*?"attributeName":"PIN CODE".*?}).*') from person ;

ERROR:  Invalid content of repeat range
DETAIL:  
  -----------------------------------------------
  error:  Invalid content of repeat range
  code:      8002
  context:   T_regexp_init
  query:     528401
  location:  funcs_expr.cpp:130
  process:   query2_40 [pid=12603]
  -----------------------------------------------
```

I guess the problem is occurring because of multiple `attributeName` in a single column. Is their a way to achieve the desired result.

Comment: You should escape curly braces as `\{`, otherwise it's assumed as a quantifier like `\w{2,5}`. That's why it throws the error `"Invalid content of repeat range"`

Comment: @Mario Sorry didnt worked, got the same error

Comment: Any chance you can create a fiddle?

Comment: Start by providing an exact table definition.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if I understood you correctly, but you can try to use LIKE:

```
    select * from person where attributes LIKE '%"attributeName":"PIN CODE"%';
```

Comment: @IvanNo I want the subtring {"attributeName":"PIN CODE","attributeMetadata":null,"attributeValue":"32110","attributeImageType":"IMG","attributeStatusCodes":[]}. The string above(in the question) is in a single column